# I can't disable http requests for my Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, ssl, https

I created a Nodejs/Express API app and uploaded to Google App Engine.

It works fine.

But it accepts HTTP (not-secure) requests and HTTPS.

I tried to disable the HTTP requests with the following config:

```
// app.yaml

runtime: nodejs
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Even after the new upload of the project, it still accepts HTTP requests and not redirects to HTTPS.

What I'm doing wrong?

(I don't want to use a custom domain, just the `my-project.appspot.com`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine Flexible doesn't support using options like `secure` and `redirect_http_response_code` as stated in [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml) in the `app.yaml` file.

My suggestion would be either move this application that you have to the Standard environment, which now supports Node and has these features that you want to use, or to manually do the redirection in your code.